# Classification for series of lat, lon points of varying lengths

Tags: classification, spatial

I have a dataset of series of latitude and longitude points. Each series of points corresponds to some activity. The number of latitude/longitude points is not the same for the series.

My dataset looks something like this:

*Series*

```
Series Time    Lat  Lon
     1    1  -43.0 97.2
     1    2  -43.1 97.2
     1    3  -43.1 97.2
     1    4  -43.1 97.3
     :    :      :    :
     2    1  -37.8 96.2
     2    2  -37.8 96.3
     2    3  -37.9 96.2
     2    4  -37.9 96.2
     2    5  -37.9 96.1
     :    :      :    :
```

*Classifications*

```
Series Activity
     1        A
     2        A
     3        C
     4        B
     5        C
     :        :
```

So for each series there a number of latitude and longitude points that occur across time.

My question, is how to classify these series of points when they have different numbers of observations?

Comment: The table under "classifications" in this post makes it seem like the series are *already* classified. What exactly is your input and what is the desired output from an answer to your question?

Comment: Of course, it is not clustering but classification -- the label here is known. The desired goal is to be able to automatically classify *new* series in the future based on any features of the series.

Comment: Well, then, what kinds of features are of importance? Knowing the actual *meanings* of these points--whether they represent sets of points, vertices of paths, boundaries of polygonal regions, pixels in images, or something else--is crucial to developing appropriate procedures.

Comment: The points correspond to a path. Things like direction, speed, and changes in these could be important. These could be projected as pixels in an image but they would all be of different sizes.

Comment: To use speed, you would need to include a time value in each data record. "Direction" on the globe hasn't the same universal inherent meaning it has on the plane, either, so perhaps you mean relative direction or maybe direction relative to the meridian? The need to consider such details indicates there is no automatic or universal solution, because much of this information has to be derived from the data. Thus, unless you are specific and complete about the features you want to use, you will (at best) get only generic and not fully useful answers.